# Activerecord where array with less than condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an array of conditions i'm passing to where(), with the conditions being added one at a time such as

```
conditions[:key] = values[:key]
...
search = ModelName.where(conditions)
```

which works fine for all those that i want to compare with '=', however I want to add a '<=' condition to the array instead of '=' such as

```
conditions[:key <=] = values[:key]
```

which of course won't work. Is there a way to make this work so it i can combine '=' clauses with '<=' clauses in the same condition array?

Comment: [Hash notation in ActiveRecord Queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

Comment: Also, take a look at [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

You could use `<=` in a `where` clause like this:

```
   User.where('`users`.`age` <= ?', 20)
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`age` <= 20)
```

#### Update_1:

For multiple conditions, you could do this:

```
User.where('`users`.`age` <= ?', 20).where('`users`.`name` = ?', 'Rakib')
```

#### Update_2:

Here is another way for multiple conditions in `where` clause:

```
User.where('(id >= ?) AND (name= ?)', 1, 'Rakib')
```

You can add any amount of `AND` `OR` conditions like this in your `ActiveRecord` `where` clause. I just showed with 2 to keep it simple.

See [Ruby on Rails Official Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) for `Array Conditions` for more information.

#### Update_3:

Another slight variation of how to use `Array Conditions` in `where` clause:

```
conditions_array = ["(id >= ?) AND (name = ?)", 1, "Rakib"]
User.where(conditions_array)
```

I think, this one will fit your exact requirement.

Comment: What I keep getting when i try to do this is WHERE "`users`.`age` <= 20" so it's inserting double quotes around the whole clause. I think the issue is i have several clauses stored in an array, which is being passed to where() instead of passing a single string with the value as the second param.

Comment: @xd6_ See my updated answer. You can easily chain your `where` clauses for multiple conditions like above. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: @xd6_ Please look at my `Update_3`, I think this will work for you. Let me know if not!

Answer (score 1):

You could use arel.

```
conditions = {x: [:eq, 1], y: [:gt, 2]}

model_names = ModelName.where(nil)

conditions.each do |field, options|
  condition = ModelName.arel_table[field].send(*options)
  model_names = model_names.where(condition)
end

model_names.to_sql --> 'SELECT * FROM model_names WHERE x = 1 and y > 2'
```